ag-grid Custom Cell Editor with popup component doesn't return focus to the grid cell?
I'm currently using ag-grid with a custom cell editor that uses MUI's Autocomplete (which opens a Popper.js window).  After the user selects something in that window, it doesn't seem to return focus to the previously selected cell (I'm guessing that the focus was moved to the popper window).
I'm able to hack together a solution that captures the focused cell and then set's the focused cell but am wondering if there's a built-in ag-grid solution to this problem?
